# Do you put an accent on qué if it is being used as what but in a sentence and not a question?

Tags: acentuación, preguntas

So, I know most question words in Spanish have an accent in their question forms and then drop it when in a sentence to respond, for example:

*¿Sabes dónde está la biblioteca?*
*Sí, yo sé donde la bibloteca está.*

But, I know that "que" without an accent, can mean many things like than, that, all transition words relating things. I also do not know if you would need a direct object pronoun + "que" every time you are referring to a "what" in a sentence, and if that were the case, then that would answer my question. But my question is, if I use "que" to mean what just like in a question but in a sentence, would it still contain the accent?

For example if I were trying to say:
*I don't know what this is about.*
*No sé que/qué este es sobre.*

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I don't know what this is about. No sé sobre qué es esto.

Answer (score 1):

In the pair of sentences:

> ¿Sabes dónde está la biblioteca? Sí, yo sé donde la biblioteca está.

"dónde" should have a written stress in both cases. In the second sentence, which should be rephrased as follows to sound more natural, "dónde" introduces a noun clause:

- Sí, yo sé dónde está la biblioteca.

Actually, in the question:

- ¿Sabes dónde está la biblioteca?

"dónde" functions in exactly the same way.

Proof that the clauses with "dónde" are nominal is that both can be replaced with a pronoun:

- ¿Sabes eso?
- Sí, yo sé eso.

Now, "dónde" can also introduce direct or indirect questions, and carries a written stress in both cases:

- ¿Dónde está la biblioteca?
- Quiero saber dónde está la biblioteca.

"Donde" (as well as similar words *cuando, quien, que, como, cuanto*) will only do without a written stress when it introduces an adverbial clause (i.e. a clause expressing the time, place, manner of the main action) or a relative clause (i.e. a clause modifying a noun):

- Te veré donde está la biblioteca. (Te veré allí, en ese lugar: adverbial of place, since it describes the place where the speaker will see the other person, that is, the place where the main action occurs)
- El lugar donde me siento más cómodo es la biblioteca. ("donde me siento más cómodo" defines the noun "lugar", and that makes it a relative or adjectival clause)

Therefore, the fact that the words in question appear in questions or exclamations does not guarantee that they will take a written stress -- that is, unless they introduce those questions or exclamations:

- ¿Qué es eso?
- ¿De qué se trata?
- No sé de qué se trata.
- ¿Qué es este sobre?
- No sé qué es este sobre.

Now, notice these cases where "que" is not stressed:

- ¿Ese es el sobre que trajo el cartero? (Is that the envelope that the mailman brought?)
- ¿Sabes que el sobre contiene una amenaza? (Do you know that the envelope contains a threat?)

It is true that, in the particular case of "que/qué", it will always be stressed when equivalent to "what" and unstressed when equivalent to "that", irrespective of the form of the sentence (interrogative or not).

The only case where the Spanish for "what" is not stressed takes place when it is translated as nominal relative "lo que", that is, "the thing that":

- ¿Sabes lo que es eso? (Do you know what that is?)
- No sé lo que es. (I don't know what it is.)

Answer (score 0):

> Las palabras qué, cuál/es, quién/es, cómo, cuán, cuánto/a/os/as, cuándo, dónde y adónde son tónicas y se escriben con tilde diacrítica **cuando tienen sentido interrogativo o exclamativo**. Estas palabras, por sí solas o precedidas de alguna preposición, introducen oraciones interrogativas o exclamativas directas:

```
      ¿Qué ha dicho?
```

> También introducen oraciones interrogativas o exclamativas indirectas, integradas en otros enunciados:

```
      Ya verás qué bien lo pasamos.
```

> Además, pueden funcionar como sustantivos:

```
      En este trabajo lo importante no es el qué, sino el cuánto.
```

> Sin embargo, cuando estas mismas palabras funcionan como adverbios o pronombres relativos o, en el caso de algunas de ellas, también como conjunciones, son átonas (salvo el relativo cual, que es tónico cuando va precedido de artículo) y se escriben sin tilde:

```
      El jefe, que no sabía nada, no supo reaccionar.
```

<sub>*Source [RAE](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/tilde-en-que-cuales-quienes-como-cuan-cuantoaosas-cuando-donde-y-adonde#:%7E:text=Las%20palabras%20qu%C3%A9%2C%20cu%C3%A1l%2Fes,tienen%20sentido%20interrogativo%20o%20exclamativo.)*</sub>